# How to make symlinks appear as regular folders to dropbox client

Tags: mount, dropbox, symbolic-link

So recently Dropbox stopped syncing symlinks (bad move IMHO). I have a rather small hard drive and use symlinks to sync folders on Dropbox. Recently this stopped working (any new files added to symlinked folders does not get uploaded anymore but older files remain).

I want to continue using my dropbox client to span multiple drives, which I had earlier done using symlinks. Now since these don't work, I want to fool the Dropbox client to thinking they are legitimate folders. I tried  `mound -o bind` but that does not work either.

What other methods could I try?

EDIT: 
`mount -o bind` does not work as it results in 0 byte files on Dropbox website and other clients, so the contents of such folders are also not synced.

Using Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: `mount -o bind`?

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not useful. What does it do instead of working?

Comment: Have edited the question explaining the behaviour for `mount -o bind`.

Comment: Can you try again? Mount bind works deep into the system, and I would be very surprised if an app could detect a folder that is connected with a mount bind. Or try stopping Dropbox while you are executing the bind to restart it after.